# Stable $\infty$-categories of derived equivalent varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

When two varieties have equivalent derived categories of coherent sheaves are the stable $\infty$-categories of coherent sheaves also equivalent?

Are the stable $\infty$-categories of varieties "discrete" in some sense?

Comment: I think this paper sums up well the state of the art. Everything you'll find will be DG. Algebraic geometers are not that much interested in non linear enhancements https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.04404

Comment: That is great but I expected it would be true without input on the level of Orlov's theorem. Is there a more trivial argument?

Comment: @tiapal Why do you expect it to have a trivial argument? It does not look like a trivial result to me...

Comment: @tiapal And if a "trivial argument" exists, it would probably imply Orlov's theorem (since enhanced functors are essentially the same as Fourier-Mukai functors).

Comment: No one seems to have addressed your second question. When the canonical bundle of $X$ is ample, Bondal-Orlov says that you can reconstruct $X$ from its (bounded coherent) derived category $D(X)$, so presumably the answer is no, $D(X)$ (and its $\infty$ version) "should have moduli". I don't know what the precise statement would be.

Answer (score 6):

Orlov proved that any derived equivalence (of smooth projective varieties) is realized by a Fourier-Mukai functor; this should imply equivalence on $\infty$-level.

Answer (score 4):

The answer of this question in the language of $(\infty,1)$-categories can be found in the following paper by Benjamin Antieau, [On the uniqueness of infinity-categorical enhancements of triangulated categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01526). Where it is shown that derived categories admit unique $\infty$-categorical enhancements ( by stable $(\infty,1)$-categories ). See Theorem 6.4 and Corollary 6.5.